# Firestore realtime listener returning undefined after value in document updated

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, I have an existing collection called lists. I also have a realtime listener like so (Function 1):

```
firebase.firestore().collection('lists').doc(listId)
.onSnapshot(listSnapshot => {
  if (listSnapshot.exists) {
    // Do something
  }
});
```

Elsewhere, I have function that updates every list in a collection (Function 2):

```
firebase.firestore().collection('lists').get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
  querySnapshot.forEach(docSnapshot => {
  firebase.firestore().collection('lists').doc(docSnapshot.id).update({ modDate: Date.now() });
  });      
});
```

Under most conditions, Function 1 is called upon startup of the app. In that case, the document corresponding to listId is returned by the listener. Then, at some later time, when that document is updated via Function 2, it then results in the Function 1 listener being fired again, returning the updated values for the document corresponding to listId. That is all expected behavior.

However, once in a while, Function 2 is actually called before or roughly concurrent with Function 1 during startup. In that case, updating the existing document via Function 2 leads to Function 1 firing, but returning undefined values (e.g. listSnapshot.exists is false) for the document corresponding to listId. Now, if it was strictly a race condition, I could see Function 1 returning the old values for the document corresponding to listId. But I get no values at all, which is what typically occurs when a document has been deleted (not updated).

I can modify my logic to ensure that Function 2 only ever runs after the former, but I'd like to understand the root of the issue.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is.  If no data exists yet in the first query, of course the callback will tell you nothing exists.  Are you expecting something different?

Comment: Updated the description. Data exists already. The second function merely updates the data. In no other instance have I seen a listener return undefined unless the document doesn't exist. It's as though the listener is waiting for a response, sees an update, and tries to match it a non-existent cached value.